# SQL Data as XML Element

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am somewhat new on generating XML out with SQL. I am trying to generate XML from this query:

```
SELECT RptType, DataType, Branch, ACC, Actual 
FROM ReportingTb
```

The query produces the following results:

```
RptType   DataType   Branch    Acc    Actual
-------   --------   -------   ----   -----------
MTD       UPS        Arizona   Total  2279.00000
MTD       UPS        Arizona   Oral   543.00000
MTD       UPS        Arizona   Tube   532.00000
MTD       UPS        Arizona   Other  1.00000
```

I want to use the query results in the first 4 columns the actual as XML elements like this:

```
<MTD>
  <UPS>
    <Arizona>
      <Total>
        <Actual>2279.00000</Actual>
      </Total>
      <Oral>
        <Actual>543.00000</Actual>
      </Oral>
      <Tube>
        <Actual>532.00000</Actual>
      </Tube>
      <Other>
        <Actual>1.00000</Actual>
      </Other>
    </Arizona>
  <UPS>
</MTD>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to do this? Should I maybe use T-SQL and loop through the results of the query in order make the XML file?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You cannot do that - you cannot use a value like `9200` to become a XML tag in your output XML. You can only use the values from the SQL Server table as XML **attribute** or **element** values - you cannot use those to create XML structure.

Comment: It's not about a *number* - you just **cannot** use a **value** as a XML tag name!

Comment: what would the XML be like if there are different `RptType`, `DataType`, and/or   `Branch` values? Currently, your sample data have only one distinct value for each of those columns. Or we can assume they always contain the same data?

Comment: The distinct values for The DataType would only be UPS and SOC, and Branch could be any state. ACC would only have the 4 values that are shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's technically possible, but it's really bad for a few reasons.  Instead, you should rethink your XML structure, to something more like this:

```
<Root>
  <ReportingTb RptType="MTD" DataType="UPS" Branch="Arizona">
    <Actual Acc="Total">2279.00000</Actual>
    <Actual Acc="Oral">543.00000</Actual>
    <Actual Acc="Tube">532.00000</Actual>
    <Actual Acc="Other">1.00000</Actual>
  </ReportingTb>
</Root>
```

Using this query:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (RptType varchar(20),   DataType VARCHAR(20),   Branch VARCHAR(20),    Acc VARCHAR(20),   Actual numeric(10,5));
INSERT @t VALUES
('MTD',  'UPS'        ,'Arizona',   'Total',  2279.00000)
,('MTD',  'UPS'        ,'Arizona',   'Oral',  543.00000)
,('MTD',  'UPS'        ,'Arizona',   'Tube',  532.00000)
,('MTD',  'UPS'        ,'Arizona',   'Other',  1.00000);

SELECT RptType as '@RptType'
    ,DataType as '@DataType'
    ,Branch as '@Branch'
    ,(SELECT 
         Acc AS '@Acc'
        ,Actual as '*'
    FROM @t t2
    WHERE t2.RptType = t1.RptType AND t2.DataType = t1.DataType AND t2.Branch = t1.Branch
    FOR XML PATH('Actual'), TYPE)
FROM @t t1
GROUP BY RptType, DataType, Branch
FOR XML PATH('ReportingTb'), ROOT('Root');
```

This gives you XML that can be sensibly validated against a schema (instead of a schema that has to contain many possible node names).  It will handle different grouping possibilities more naturally, and it will take care of all the XML weirdness that `FOR XML` handles behind the scenes.

That said, it is technically possible to achieve your original desire; here's a query that would do it:

```
SELECT 
    CAST('<' + RptType + '>'
    + (SELECT 
        '<' + DataType + '>' 
        + (SELECT
            '<' + Branch + '>'
            + REPLACE(REPLACE(
            (SELECT
                 '#' + acc + '!' as '*' , Actual, '#/' + acc + '!' as '*'
                FROM @t t4 WHERE t4.Branch = t3.Branch AND t4.DataType = t2.DataType AND t4.RptType = t1.RptType
                FOR XML PATH('')), '#', '<'), '!', '>')

            + '</' + Branch + '>'
            FROM  @t t3  WHERE t3.DataType = t2.DataType AND t3.RptType = t1.RptType GROUP BY Branch)
        + '</' + DataType + '>'
        FROM @t t2  WHERE t2.RptType = t1.RptType GROUP BY DataType)
    + '</' + RptType + '>'  AS XML)
FROM @t t1
GROUP BY RptType
```

**Note that you should not do this, it's really ugly hackery** (I'm only showing you to give you an idea of how ugly even to get part of the way there).  It really only gets worse.  I'm using weird string replaces that may or may not work in the wild.  On top of that, if any node has an invalid XML character, you'd have to escape it - maybe throw in some additional replaces (`REPLACE(col, '<', '&lt;')`) or something, but again that's ugly and has to be repeated all over for several values.  You're basically using SQL Server as an XML Writer, and it's really not meant to do that.  If you absolutely **must** have this structure, then you should pass the data to a CLR class that can properly use something like `XmlWriter` or `XDocument` to write the actual XML using these values.  You could even put the CLR class in SQL Server and call it from the stored procedure.